# Queues and Stacks and References

Tags: c++, pointers, stack

I'm getting a segfault on an issue having to do with getting references to the top elements in queues and stacks. I'll focus on the stack here. I want to determine if the segfault occurs because of improper syntax or due to some other reason in the code.

When i pop the top element of stack (order) of type path, i set a pointer to it.

```
*square=order.top();//I want square to point to the path element so I can access it's details
```

Keep in mind that *square points to another variable of type path before this.

I then generally end up popping it off the stack but if i'm not mistaken, square should still have access to the data.

Comment: If your `pop` frees the element, `square` will not have access to it. You'll need to make a copy of the element, and have `square` point to that copy instead. It would help if you show us the code that does the popping, as well as the lines of code surrounding the line you've pasted (i.e. including the initialization of `square` and the subsequent `pop`)

Comment: Are you trying to change the pointer (`ptr = ...`) or the value (`*ptr = ...`)? Right now you're changing the value, and not the address.

Comment: so i think i'm figuring out what i did wrong, generally i have square pointing to the top element, then pop it off right away with the thinking that square would still be able to see it but I have to make a copy I guess. So to make a copy of this struct, would i just do path temp=*square ?

Comment: Does your `pop` call `delete`? If yes, you'll need to do a `new` again, and initialize it with the data from the element you have just popped out.

Comment: There's no new or delete being used, I have elements of an array being loaded in, than peek at the top, pop, and try to look at the data from the peeked element to make a judgement on what to do next

Comment: I believe `path temp = *square` will do the job of copying then. (You won't need `square` in fact - that is, you don't need a pointer, use a value type instead)

Comment: Why don't you change the order of operations: peek at the top, look at the data and decide what to do next, and **then** pop once you no longer need the element. Then you won't need a copy.